# Is it possilbe to order many-to-many relation in JPA using a custom integer value stored in the join table?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, `Employer` and `Language`, with a many-to-many relation between them. Each `Employer` can have multiple `Language` enitites, and they have a preferred order of the languages that they can speak. I want to store the preferred order in join table and retrieve it by ordered `List<Language>` but I am not sure how to implement it in JPA.

Here's an example of my `Employer` and `Language` entities:

```
@Entity
public class Employer {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    //.....
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Language> languages;
    //.....
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    //.....
}
```

This is how the database tables might look like:

```
employer table:
| id | bigint |
....

language table:
| id | bigint |
....

employer_language table:
| employer_id | bigint |
| language_id | bigint |
| order_index | int    |
```

Does JPA allow to do this?

I have considered to use a Map field that contains a `Language` as key and an order index by value but I think there could be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to use the `@OrderColumn` annotation. In your example, you would have something like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    //.....
}

@Entity
public class Employer {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    //.....
    @ManyToMany
    @OrderColumn(name = "order_index")
    private List<Language> languages;
    //.....
}
```